# Run Python script in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, python, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, ironpython

How should I go about running a python script in Windows Phone 7 or 8 with IronPython. I have tried by doing the following:

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("Test.py");
```

But I then get this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Microsoft.Scripting.DLL
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

The Test.py simply contains:

```
print "Hello World"
```

Comment: Where is the documentation that says that python works in a WinPhone?

Comment: IronPython does indeed have a build option for WP 7 which builds fine, then imports fine but finally gives this error

Answer (score 1):

IronPython doesn't support Windows Phone. However, you can use starcore.Python which has been compiled for windows phone. Check [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/using-python-on-windows-e914e5c5/view/SourceCode) sample on msdn.

Comment: I have tried it but for some strange reason the author of starcore decided that WP 8 does not support threading and removed it from starcore, this is a problem because the application I ultimately intend on running is heavily reliant on the thread module

Comment: As far as I know that's the only python lib compiled for WP8.

Comment: IPY has definitely been compiled for WP I am just struggling to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The [release info](http://blog.ironpython.net/2012/07/whats-new-in-ironpython-273.html) for the current stable release (2.7.3) of IronPython states that:

> Windows Phone support has been dropped because there were serious issues with the current version, and WP7’s days are numbered. Instead focus will shift to WinRT (“Metro”) which will work in Windows 8 and Window Phone 8.

That means that whatever code is there (remaining legacy, work in progress) seems to be currently unsupported.